# Severity: Warning Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'asboha'

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

When I Use Codeignter Framework and add database name I get this error
I'm used XAMPP server and I am changed from 8000 to 8080

My code in config database.php

```
 $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost:3306',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'asboha',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' =>FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
```

[image]

Comment: try replace localhost:3306 with localhost:3308

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate `hostname` and `port`. e.g.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 3306,
```

Comment: iam do it but no the same error 

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'asboha'

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 203

Backtrace:

Comment: Have you got such database in your MySQL server?

Comment: Yes I have one what i can do ?

Comment: You need to debug to see what values are really being used in the connection. Check if the port is passed it right. Maybe there's a typo somewhere or invisible space.